# Trying to make a simple Tic Tac Toe game in Javascript for an assignment. No errors, but nothing happens when I click the boxes

Tags: javascript

so I'm in a beginner web programming course, and my assignment is to make a Tic Tac Toe game in Javascript. My teacher provided a template for use to fill out, which should have been really simple. I've followed each instruction to the letter as best as I could, but I've run into a problem where nothing happens when I click the boxes. No errors or messages, nothing. Chrome isn't showing me any errors, so I have no idea where to even look. Could anyone point me in the right direction? I'm hoping that it's just silly beginner mistake. Here's what I have:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- style settings-->
        <style>
            .tictac
            {
                background:purple;
                border:#999 10px groove;
                width:180px;
                height:180px;
                font-size:150px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            // create a variable for if the game is over, initialize it to false
            var gameOver = false;

            // create a variable for the current player, initialize it to 'O' or 'X'
            // based on who will go first
            if(confirm("Does X want to go first?") == true)
            { 
                var player = 'X';
            }
            else
            { 
                var player = 'O';
            }


            // create an array for the squares using the regular methodology
            var squares = new Array();
                squares[0] = 0;
                squares[1] = 1;
                squares[2] = 2;
                squares[3] = 3;
                squares[4] = 4;
                squares[5] = 5;
                squares[6] = 6;
                squares[7] = 7;
                squares[8] = 8;

            // create a 2-d array of the win combinations, the data is as follows:
            /*
                0, 1, 2
                3, 4, 5
                6, 7, 8
                0, 3, 6
                1, 4, 7
                2, 5, 8
                0, 4, 8
                2, 4, 6

            */
            var winCombinations = [
                [0, 1, 2],
                [3, 4, 5],
                [6, 7, 8],
                [0, 3, 6],
                [1, 4, 7],
                [2, 5, 8],
                [0, 4, 8],
                [2, 4, 6]
            ];

            // declare function named reset with no parameters
            function reset()
            {
                // write a for loop starting at index 1 instead of the 
                // usual 0, that loops through all 9 positions
                for (var i = 1; i < squares.length + 1; i++)
                {
                    // create a variable to relate to each HTML button,
                    // set it equal to explicit text "sqr" concatenated
                    // with the looping variable of the for loop
                    var htmlButton = "sqr" + i;

                    // update the associated HTML element with the id
                    // equal to the variable created above, set it equal
                    // to and explicit empty string

                }                   

                // reset the global variable for the squares to an 
                // empty array using the literal methodology
                squares = [];

                // reset the global variable for the game being over
                // setting it equal to false
                gameOver = false;

            }

            //declare function named squareClick with parameter square
            function squareClick(square)
            {   
                // create a variable that is set equal to the HTML element
                // with the id of square (i.e. the parameter) and retrieve its value
                var idElement = document.getElementById(squares).value;
                // this will be used down below as the id to update the HTML element

                // create a variable that is set equal to the JavaScript method call
                // parseInt() passing as an argument square.substring(3, 4), 
                // subtract one from the result of the parseInt method call
                var parseSquare = ((parseInt(square.substring(3, 4))) - 1);
                // this will represent the index of the array of squares where
                // the user clicked

                // write an if statement that evaluates if the variable
                // value is equal to explicit string ""
                if(idElement = "")
                {
                    // update the HTML element using the parameter square as
                    // the id, setting its value equal to the global variable
                    // player
                    document.getElementById(square).value = player;

                    // in array of the squares update element stored at
                    // the index retrieved above to the global variable
                    // player
                    squares[index] = player;
                }

                // call the function checkForWinner passing as an argument
                // the explicit value 'X'
                checkForWinner('X');

                // call the function checkForWinner passing as an argument
                // the explicit value 'O'
                checkForWinner('O');

                // change the player
                // write an if statement that checks if the player variable
                // is equal to O, if true, set player to X
                if(player == 'O')
                    player = 'X';
                // write the else leg that switches player from X to O
                else
                    player = 'O';
            }

            function playAgain()
            {
                // create a variable that stores the response to a
                // confirm dialog box with text "Play again?"
                var response = confirm("Play again?");
                // write an if statement that evaluates the user's response
                // from above compared to true
                if (response == true) 
                {
                    alert("Let's play!");
                    reset ();
                }
                // write the else leg
                else 
                {
                    alert("Thanks for playing!");
                }
            }

            // declare function checkForWinner with one parameter called value
            function checkForWinner(value)
            {   
                // write for loop, start at index 0, loop while
                // the index less than the length of the array
                // winCombinations
                for(var i = 0; i < winCombinations.length; i++)
                {
                    // write an if statement that evaluates
                    // the squares array [] where the index is
                    // array winCombinations[][], with the first index
                    // being the looping variable and the second index 
                    // being value 0, 1, or 2, checking if it is 
                    // equal to the value parameter;
                    // this if statement should be 
                    // three statements using the logical and &&
                    // e.g. squares[windCombinations[][]]  == value &&
                    if(squares[winCombinations[i][0]] == value && squares[winCombinations[i][1]] == value && squares[winCombinations[i][2]] == value)
                    {
                        // display an alert dialog box stating which
                        // player won
                        alert(value + "won the game!");
                        // set the variable gameOver equal to true
                        gameOver == true;
                    }                   
                }

                // write an if statement checking if gameOver is true
                if(gameOver == true)
                {
                    // call function playAgain
                    playAgain();
                }
                // write the else leg
                else
                {
                    // use the return statement for program control
                    return("It's the next player's move!");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr1" name="sqr1" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr1')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr2" name="sqr2" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr2')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr3" name="sqr3" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr3')" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr4" name="sqr4" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr4')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr5" name="sqr5" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr5')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr6" name="sqr6" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr6')" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr7" name="sqr7" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr7')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr8" name="sqr8" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr8')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr9" name="sqr9" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr9')" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). i.e. delete as much code as possible and still have the error then fix it

Comment: I bet you only need one square so delete the other 8, and I bet you can replace squareClick definition with "alert('hello')" or something

Comment: Everything else runs fine?

Comment: No errors? Thats strange cause I immediately get an error in the console when I click on a square. Open the developer console in chrome `CTRL + SHIFT + I`. Select the console tab when the developer tools open. Refresh the page and then click on one of the squares. You will see your first error message.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem. It really was just some beginner mistakes, namely using only "=" instead of "==" in my if-statement, and trying to use a variable that didn't exist. I must have missed something in the developer console, because I really don't think I saw any errors pop up. It's all good now though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were basically two errors in your code:

1. if statement is an attribution rather than comparison: `if(idElement = "")`. It should be `if(idElement === "")`
2. `squares[index] = player;`. `index` doesn't exist. Should be `squares[parseSquare] = player;`

```js
// create a variable for if the game is over, initialize it to false
var gameOver = false;

// create a variable for the current player, initialize it to 'O' or 'X'
// based on who will go first
if(confirm("Does X want to go first?") == true)
{ 
  var player = 'X';
}
else
{ 
  var player = 'O';
}


// create an array for the squares using the regular methodology
var squares = new Array();
squares[0] = 0;
squares[1] = 1;
squares[2] = 2;
squares[3] = 3;
squares[4] = 4;
squares[5] = 5;
squares[6] = 6;
squares[7] = 7;
squares[8] = 8;

// create a 2-d array of the win combinations, the data is as follows:
/*
                0, 1, 2
                3, 4, 5
                6, 7, 8
                0, 3, 6
                1, 4, 7
                2, 5, 8
                0, 4, 8
                2, 4, 6

            */
var winCombinations = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
];

// declare function named reset with no parameters
function reset()
{
  // write a for loop starting at index 1 instead of the 
  // usual 0, that loops through all 9 positions
  for (var i = 1; i < squares.length + 1; i++)
  {
    // create a variable to relate to each HTML button,
    // set it equal to explicit text "sqr" concatenated
    // with the looping variable of the for loop
    var htmlButton = "sqr" + i;

    // update the associated HTML element with the id
    // equal to the variable created above, set it equal
    // to and explicit empty string

  }                   

  // reset the global variable for the squares to an 
  // empty array using the literal methodology
  squares = [];

  // reset the global variable for the game being over
  // setting it equal to false
  gameOver = false;

}

//declare function named squareClick with parameter square
function squareClick(square)
{   
  // create a variable that is set equal to the HTML element
  // with the id of square (i.e. the parameter) and retrieve its value
  var idElement = document.getElementById(square).value;
  // this will be used down below as the id to update the HTML element

  // create a variable that is set equal to the JavaScript method call
  // parseInt() passing as an argument square.substring(3, 4), 
  // subtract one from the result of the parseInt method call
  var parseSquare = ((parseInt(square.substring(3, 4))) - 1);
  // this will represent the index of the array of squares where
  // the user clicked
  // write an if statement that evaluates if the variable
  // value is equal to explicit string ""
  if(idElement == "")
  {
    // update the HTML element using the parameter square as
    // the id, setting its value equal to the global variable
    // player
    document.getElementById(square).value = player;

    // in array of the squares update element stored at
    // the index retrieved above to the global variable
    // player
    squares[parseSquare] = player;
  }

  // call the function checkForWinner passing as an argument
  // the explicit value 'X'
  checkForWinner('X');

  // call the function checkForWinner passing as an argument
  // the explicit value 'O'
  checkForWinner('O');

  // change the player
  // write an if statement that checks if the player variable
  // is equal to O, if true, set player to X
  if(player == 'O')
    player = 'X';
  // write the else leg that switches player from X to O
  else
    player = 'O';
}

function playAgain()
{
  // create a variable that stores the response to a
  // confirm dialog box with text "Play again?"
  var response = confirm("Play again?");
  // write an if statement that evaluates the user's response
  // from above compared to true
  if (response == true) 
  {
    alert("Let's play!");
    reset ();
  }
  // write the else leg
  else 
  {
    alert("Thanks for playing!");
  }
}

// declare function checkForWinner with one parameter called value
function checkForWinner(value)
{   
  // write for loop, start at index 0, loop while
  // the index less than the length of the array
  // winCombinations
  for(var i = 0; i < winCombinations.length; i++)
  {
    // write an if statement that evaluates
    // the squares array [] where the index is
    // array winCombinations[][], with the first index
    // being the looping variable and the second index 
    // being value 0, 1, or 2, checking if it is 
    // equal to the value parameter;
    // this if statement should be 
    // three statements using the logical and &&
    // e.g. squares[windCombinations[][]]  == value &&
    if(squares[winCombinations[i][0]] == value && squares[winCombinations[i][1]] == value && squares[winCombinations[i][2]] == value)
    {
      // display an alert dialog box stating which
      // player won
      alert(value + "won the game!");
      // set the variable gameOver equal to true
      gameOver == true;
    }                   
  }

  // write an if statement checking if gameOver is true
  if(gameOver == true)
  {
    // call function playAgain
    playAgain();
  }
  // write the else leg
  else
  {
    // use the return statement for program control
    return("It's the next player's move!");
  }
}
```

```css
.tictac
{
  background:purple;
  border:#999 10px groove;
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
  font-size:150px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr1" name="sqr1" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr1')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr2" name="sqr2" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr2')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr3" name="sqr3" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr3')" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr4" name="sqr4" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr4')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr5" name="sqr5" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr5')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr6" name="sqr6" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr6')" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr7" name="sqr7" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr7')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr8" name="sqr8" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr8')" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sqr9" name="sqr9" class="tictac" onClick="squareClick('sqr9')" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a beginner question, so I'm going to post an answer appropriate to a beginner.

> No errors or messages, nothing. Chrome isn't showing me any errors, so I have no idea where to even look.

You are correct that errors (you looked in Developer Tools > Console right?) are where to start.

The next thing you should do to find the error is *delete as much code as possible*. You have 9 squares? Make it 1. Replace as many functions as you can with very very simple definitions like `alert("This code ran");`.

Delete code until when you run it, the simpler behavior, like alerting "This code ran", starts happening.

Now you will have:

1. A very small amount of code to work through, and/or
2. A very small amount of code that you added or removed that changed the behavior.

Then research that. At that point you can probably google whatever you have trouble with and get an answer. You can post at StackOverflow if you are still stuck but I will warn you, *whatever mistake you are making has been asked here before.*

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Other people provided straight edits to my code, but I ran into some more problems afterwards, and you're suggestion to minimize the amount of code helped me get through it. I'll try and be more mindful next time I have to check for errors, and get better at checking Google first. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
            function squareClick(selectedSq)
        {   
            // create a variable that is set equal to the HTML element
            // with the id of square (i.e. the parameter) and retrieve its value
            var idElement = document.getElementById(selectedSq).value;
            // this will be used down below as the id to update the HTML element

            // create a variable that is set equal to the JavaScript method call
            // parseInt() passing as an argument square.substring(3, 4), 
            // subtract one from the result of the parseInt method call
            var parseSquare = ((parseInt(selectedSq.substring(3, 4))) - 1);
            // this will represent the index of the array of squares where
            // the user clicked

            // write an if statement that evaluates if the variable
            // value is equal to explicit string ""
            if(idElement == "")
            {
                // update the HTML element using the parameter square as
                // the id, setting its value equal to the global variable
                // player
                document.getElementById(selectedSq).value = player;

                // in array of the squares update element stored at
                // the index retrieved above to the global variable
                // player
                squares[parseSquare] = player;
            }

            // call the function checkForWinner passing as an argument
            // the explicit value 'X'
            checkForWinner('X');

            // call the function checkForWinner passing as an argument
            // the explicit value 'O'
            checkForWinner('O');

            // change the player
            // write an if statement that checks if the player variable
            // is equal to O, if true, set player to X
            if(player == 'O')
                player = 'X';
            // write the else leg that switches player from X to O
            else
                player = 'O';
        }
```

this should fix it, you missed an = sign in the if statement and referenced index when you wanted to reference parsdeSquare

Comment: not sure if editing a post here shows on the activity box so I made this comment

Answer (score 0):

```
function startGame(){
    for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
        clearBox(i);
    }
    document.player = "X";
    document.winner = null;
    setMessage("Player '" + document.player + "'s turn")
}

function setMessage(msg){
    document.getElementById("message").innerText = msg;
}

function setMessage1(msgg){
    document.getElementById("clickedBox").innerText = msgg;
}

function nextMove(square){
    if(document.winner != null){
        alert("Player " + document.player + " already won");
    }else if(square.innerText == ''){

        square.innerText = document.player;
        if(document.getElementById("square"+1).innerText == "X"){
            a.push("Player X: Clicked box 1");
        } 
        setMessage1(removeDups(a).join("\n"));
        nextPlayer();       

    }else{
        alert("Square is already used, please choose another square");
    }
}

function nextPlayer(){
    if(checkWinner(document.player)){
        alert("Player " + document.player + " you won");
        //Getting the score of each player
        if(document.player == "X"){
        player1Score+= 1
        }
        else if(document.player == "O"){
        player2Score+= 1
        }
        document.getElementById("score1").innerText = player1Score;
        document.getElementById("score2").innerText = player2Score;
        //End
        setMessage("Click RESTART to play again");
        document.winner = document.player;
    }else if(checkTie()){
        setMessage("Its a TIE, click RESTART to play again");
    }else if(document.player == "X"){
        document.player = "O";
        setMessage("'" + document.player + "'s turn")
    }else{
        document.player = "X";
        setMessage("'" + document.player + "'s turn")
    }
}

function checkWinner(move){
    var result = false;
    if( checkRow(1, 2, 3, move) ||
        checkRow(4, 5, 6, move) ||
        checkRow(7, 8, 9, move) ||
        checkRow(1, 4, 7, move) ||
        checkRow(1, 5, 9, move) ||
        checkRow(3, 5, 7, move) ||
        checkRow(2, 5, 8, move) ||
        checkRow(3, 6, 9, move)){
        result = true;
    }
        return result;
}

function checkTie(){
    for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
        if(getBox(i) == '')
            return false;           
    }
            return true;
}

function checkRow(a, b, c, move){
    var result = false;
    if(getBox(a) == move && getBox(b) == move && getBox(c) == move){
        result = true;
    }
        return result;
}

function getBox(number){
    return document.getElementById("square" + number).innerText;
}

function clearBox(number){
    document.getElementById("square" + number). innerText = '';
}
```